# Edit lines in string array and writing into new array c#

Tags: c#

I'm new with coding, I have a batch file that I read into strings array, now I'm looking for specific words and then I would like to edit them and write all array lines into a new batch file.

for example 
my batch file is:

> set image1=
>   set image2=

---

I would like to look for "set image1=" and edit it to "set image1=c:\1.jpg"

```
  string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(batchfile);
  foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("set image1="))
```

and now I don't know how to edit it.

Comment: do you know how to do a  google search, hint `Key word is Replace, look up how to use string.Replace method`

Answer (score 3):

You could update your array. Since replacing the `line`-variable will not do anything because it is immutable.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(batchfile);
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];

    if (line.Contains("set image1=")) {
        lines[i] = "set image1=c:\\1.jpg"; // This will replace the entire line
    } 
}

// Your lines-array have now been changed with your replacements
```

*Remember to escape your `\`*

Comment: Is it necessary to use Replace - wouldn't _"lines[i] = "set image1=c:\\1.jpg";"_ work equally well